# What can cause right lower quadrant abdominal pain?

Tags: pain, cause-and-effect

Given a normal ultrasound, what are some possible causes of a dull right lower quadrant abdominal pain lasting up to a week in duration in a 30 year old female patient?

Comment: Why are people downvoting without any explanation? that doesn't help

Comment: I suspect this is one of those questions where the list of possibilities is too long.  Abdominal pain can be caused by a plethora of things.

Comment: Yes, I also think this one is actually too broad. Context is needed, and this with a specific context would require seeing a doctor.

Comment: My apologies, I downvoted because I considered this way too broad. See @Shlublu 's comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right lower quadrant pain is typically appendiceal or ovarian. It can also be salpingitis - which does last longer, or PCOS, depending on the duration of the symptoms, or cystic Lymphangioma. Finally, it could be a stone at the junction of the ureter and bladder.

Generally when a patient (or person) is asking about a symptom, they should be able to answer nine questions (O/S/Q/L/T/A/P/P/C):

> - Onset
> - Severity
> - Quality
> - Location
> - Timing
> - Associated sx
> - Palliatiated by
> - Precipitated by
> - Course.

A normal ultrasound would not rule out all of these, but would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate issue comes to my mind is appendix. However, you have defined a larger area whereas this pain is somewhere around McBurney's point. But then you say that it's a normal USG!

The area you are defining is typical for appendicitis. And if this is not the problem, the causes may range from pelvic inflammatory conditions (radiating there) to constipation and UIT to salpingitis. But who are you? A man or a woman?

Also, it depends on other symptoms and not just pain. Because 'pain' is very general (if I do workout after a week or so, I'll have pain wherever I focused during workout). And that is the reason, the pain is **always** considered with **other** symptoms or associated problems. What is the consistency of your stools, urine report, or whether it's just muscular pain etc.